# jQuery "this" selector not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to set the width of an element based on the number of children it has multiplied by the constant width of each child.  I have multiple of these elements on the page each with variable number of children.

```
 $(".parent").css("width", ($(this).children().length * 150) + "px");
```

This doesn't seem to work as I would of expected.  I expected this to find every parent class and then calculate the width based on the number of each elements respective children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working as expected because `this` is pointing to the current function scope, not `.parent`. In order to achieve what you are trying to do, you could use `each`.

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
    $(this).css("width", ($(this).children().length * 150) + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Also possible:

```
$(".parent").css("width", function () { 
   return ($(this).children().length * 150) + "px") 
});
```

[jQuery `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the order that code runs in, with variables so the order can be made clear:

```
var $this = $(this);                // Wrap whatever the current value of `this`
                                    // is in a jQuery object; note this has
                                    // nothing to do  with ".parent"
var $children = $this.children();   // Get its children
var width = $children.length * 150; // Calculate the width
width = width += "px";              // Put a "px" on it (you don't need this)
var $parent = $(".parent");         // Find the element(s) with class "parent"
$parent.css("width", width);        // Apply the width to it
```

Instead, you probably want:

```
var $parent = $(".parent");
$parent.css("width", $parent.children().length * 150); // You don't need "px"
```